# Diameter of a steel needle that can just float on water due to surface tension?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, surface-tension

γ water = 0.072    p steel = 7.8 x $10^3$
I solve the problem like this :

mg = surface tension force

p.V.g= γ.2πrL

p.π$r^2.L.g$ =γ.2πrL

r= (2γ)/(pg)

the result is different from my book. Where did i go wrong here?

Comment: what is the result in your book ?

Comment: In your equation **p.V.g= γ.2πrL** the dimensions of the left hand side are those of force and the dimensions of the right hand side they are those of force $\times$ distance.

Comment: Yes , i think it should be 2pi*r only

Comment: book's answer is 1.55mm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand side of your equation $\rho.V.g= γ.2πrL$ is incorrect.
Ignoring the ends of the needle you need the total length of the needle in contact with the water.
On the left hand side express the volume of the needle $V$ in terms of appropriate variables and you will find an equation which will enable you to find the radius $r$ of the needle, the length $L$ of the needle having cancelling out.
Hence you can evaluate the diameter of the needle.